# From 2 mySQL databases, to one

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have two database that i want to combine.
I have two values who are exactely the same in both databases.
It's `id` & `id_p`
The first database is called: `locatie`
and has: `ID, latitude, longitude, timestamp`
the other database is called: `persooninfo`
and has `id_p, voornaam, achternaam, opleiding, diploma, bezig`
Does anyone know how I can combine these two databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

--To get all the columns from locatie table

```
select l.* from   locatie l
join   persooninfo p
on     l.id=p.id_p
```

--To get all the columns from persooninfo table

```
select l.* from   locatie l
join   persooninfo p
on     l.id=p.id_p
```

----To get all the columns from persooninfo and locatie  table

```
select * from   locatie l
join   persooninfo p
on     l.id=p.id_p
```